# How to load a uitableviewcell from a single xib

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Is it possible to load a xib into a single uitableviewcell without making any unnecessary? classes?

Comment: You mean without subclassing UITableViewCell ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google is your friend:

http://www.bdunagan.com/2009/06/28/custom-uitableviewcell-from-a-xib-in-interface-builder/